# speed of accessing closure variable vs object variable

Tags: javascript, closures

Consider the following code:

```
var xx=1;
var ff=function(){
  return xx+1;
}
ff();    

var gg=function(){
  return gg.xx+1;
}
gg.xx=1;
gg();
```

Should there be any clear performance difference between these two approaches? It seems to me that the `ff` function should perform faster since it references only one variable whereas the `gg` function references two variables. I am developing a game and want to exploit every possible speed trick that I can.

Comment: There is no closure, the variable resolution (*xx* and *gg*) is identical. The second also involves a property lookup so **should** be slower, but there's no accounting for browser vagaries.

Comment: Worry more about keeping your data well organised. Performance differences in this area are going to be extremely trivial compared to others - eg driving the DOM.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has been asked [many times before](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=variable%20vs%20closure%20performance). The only difference here is that neither example would normally be called a closure, they are simple cases of variable and property resolution.

In the case of:

```
var xx = 1;
var ff = function(){
  return xx + 1;
}
```

then within the function, *xx* must first be resolved on the local variable object, and then on the scope chain. So that's two lookups at least.

In the case of:

```
var gg = function(){
  return gg.xx + 1;
}
gg.xx = 1;
```

within the function, *gg* must be resolved in exactly the same way as the first case (i.e. on the local variable object and then on the scope chain), which again is two lookups. Having found *gg*, its properties must be searched find *xx*, which may involve a number of lookups.

Given the above, it's logical to assume the first is faster.

Of course, that's just a logical deduction, performance may actually be counter to that. In some browsers, global variable lookup is faster than local regardless of the length of the scope chain. Go figure.

It is certain that performance will be different in different browsers, regardless of which way it goes. Such performance tweaks (if there is any performance benefit at all) are playing at the margins and should be treated as premature optimisation.

#### Edit

To code this as a closure requires something like;

```
var gg = (function() {
  var g;
  return function() {
    gg = function() {
      return g.xx + 1; // Here is the closure
    }

    if (typeof g == 'undefined') {
      g = gg;
    }

    if (typeof g.xx == 'undefined') {
      g.xx = 1;
    }

    return g();
  }
}());
```

since *gg* doesn't have a value until the IIFE finishes, so the closure can only be created at that point, the value can only be assigned later, when the function is fist run.

Note that *g* must still be resolved on the local variable object, then on the scope chain so still two lookups and no gain from the closure (at least no logical gain).

#### Edit 2

Just to be clear regarding closures:

```
var xx = 1;
var ff = function(){
  return xx + 1;
}
```

Does *technically* <strike>not</strike> form a closure, but not one worth recognising. The identifier *xx* is resolved on the scope chain, there are no variables on the scope chain that are accessible by *ff* when some outer execution context completes. So the closure exists only for as long as the function does and therefore is no more remarkable than lexical scope.

In contrast:

```
var ff = (function() {

  var closureVariable;

  // This "inner" function has a closure with closureVariable
  // If value is undefined, get (return) the value. Otherwise, set it
  return function(value) {
    if (typeof value == 'undefined') {
      return closureVariable;
    }
    closureVariable = value;
  };
}());
```

In this case, *ff* has exclusive access to *closureVariable*, which is a variable that remains accessible after the function that created it has completed:

```
// set the value
ff('foo');

// get the value
console.log(ff());  // foo
```

*closureVariable* is only accessible by *ff* (unlike global variables) and persists over numerous calls (unlike local variables). It's this feature of closures that allows them to [emulate private members](http://javascript.crockford.com/private.html).

Another feature is that many functions can have a closure (or priveliged access) to the same variable, emulating a kind of inheritance.

Comment: +1 for the note about premature optimisation.  Get it to work with the cleanest, most elegant, most readable code you can first.  If you have performance issues, profile it to find out where, and then fix the very worst ones until your performance is fine.  But often enough, you will find no need to go there.

Comment: "neither example would normally be called a closure" You have a messed-up definition of closure. A *closure* is any function that uses a variable from an outer scope. Both of those are closures.

Comment: @newacct—not at all, please read [Javascript Closures](http://jibbering.com/faq/notes/closures/) on the comp.lang.javascript FAQ: `A closure is formed when one of those inner functions is made accessible outside of the function in which it was contained, so that it may be executed after the outer function has returned. At which point it still has access to the local variables, parameters and inner function declarations of its outer function.` Simple variable access on a scope chain is not a closure.

Comment: @RobG: Just because somebody wrote something does not make it right. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_programming%29 "a closure is a function or reference to a function together with a referencing environment"

Comment: @newacct—I think you should do some research on the authors of that article, they are not just "somebody". The wikipedia explanation is entirely consistent with the article I referenced, you should also have quoted: `A closure ... allows a function to access those non-local variables even when invoked outside its immediate lexical scope.`

Comment: @newacct—perhaps you prefer the [MDN Closures article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures), though I doubt it's provenance is any better that the CLJ FAQ article. MDN is a public wiki that anyone can edit, the CLJ FAQ is moderated by a designated maintainer.

Comment: @RobG: I believe what I state is consistent with what is said in textbooks and literature. Rather than argue who said what, let's talk about the content. I understand your point of view -- you posit that when a function is created, it does not have access to its lexical environment, and that that environment is magically tacked on when it is "made accessible outside of the function in which it was contained". Whereas I say that it has this access when the function is created.

Comment: @RobG: The only difference between the two is when the function is within the scope that created it, and for that, you can explain accessing outside variables as accessing variables already in the stack. So there is no demonstrable difference between what we say. However, which view is simpler? Consider how the runtime would implement this. How would it detect when the function is "made accessible outside of the function in which it was contained"? One case is if it is returned. But it can also be put into some data structure, which may or may not become accessible outside of the function.

Comment: @newacct—the point of referencing articles is that they have explanations far in excess of what can be achieved in comments here. Please read the first article I referenced, the primary author (Richard Cornford) probably knows more about ECMAScript and JavaScript than anyone on this forum (bar none) and also happens to be one of the most lucid and precise technical writers you will ever encounter. I'm not going to paraphrase his article here or use comments as a discussion forum.

Comment: @RobG: I disagree. Saying "go read it" is rude as it is implying that other people are not familiar with what is said there. In any case, this discussion is not about JavaScript. General programming terms like "closure" apply to all languages and must be defined in a way that is consistent across languages. Since this is a disagreement over definitions, it cannot be resolved by any article. This is the definition that I have seen everywhere. I accept that you have a different definition, but I do not agree with it.

Comment: @RobG why is a closure only created when a function is returned from a parent function, but not when it is registered as an event listener? Seems like they are both closures to me.

Comment: @OwenMasback—event listeners aren't mentioned here, I have never said they don't form closures. Listeners forming closures is (or perhaps was) a great source of memory leaks.

Comment: @newacct—the wikipedia article you referenced and selectively quoted does not support your argument from a general programming perspective, nor from a javascript perspective. The definition of a closure that I use was written by Lasse Reichstein Nielsen, joint winner of the Aarhus University [*Most Influential Paper 10-year Award*](http://cs.au.dk/news-events/news/show-news/artikel/most-influential-paper-10-year-award-for-olivier-danvy-and-lasse-reichstein-nielsen/). Go on, tell me he doesn't know what he's talking about.

Comment: @RobG, I'm perplexed by your citation of Lasse Nielsen, since his definition of a closure contradicts yours, and agrees with OP's and newacct's. Funnily enough, I came across his definition in a thread that YOU started where *he corrected you!*. Lasse: "Every function object in Javascript is a closure, so trivially this code creates a closure... There's no requirement that the closure must survive the scope it was created in, it's a closure from the moment it's created." http://www.thecodingforums.com/threads/confusion-about-closures.942413/ . What gives?

Comment: @OwenMasback—that discussion was in [*comp.lang.javascript*](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/comp.lang.javascript/Confusion$20about$20closures/comp.lang.javascript/ExDIYdJchFw/0787e0hQ7e0J), thank you for reminding me of it. Re–reading it, I can see Lasse argues that indeed, all functions create closures but it's only those that persist after the function has completed that are of interest. That's the part my neurons chose to remember. :-) I'll update the answer when I have time.